# iOS 9 UITableview Freeze when reload(xcode 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have array objects to be loaded in tableview. My tableview delegates are

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return currentArray.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"LessonCellID";
    LessionTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];

    //210 231 246
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:238/255.0 green:238/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }else{
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:210/255.0 green:231/255.0 blue:246/255.0 alpha:1]];
    }

    cell.labelDate.text = [[currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DateCaption"];
    cell.labelTitle.text = [[currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
    return cell;
}
```

after getting values from server , my code

```
currentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
[self.tableViewSubjects reloadData];
```

when i run this code , my app freeze and I am not able to do anything. It blocks whole UI.  If I delete "reloadData" code then there is no more freezes but I want to load my data into tableview. So I have to call "reloadData".

Please anyone help me to find the cause.

Note : 
This issue occured only when I use custom cell(LessionTableViewCell or any custom cell) not on UITableviewCell class. I have my custom cell on storyboard(In my view controller nib) and created '.h' and '.m' file separately and set the cell class on File inspector.

[image: This is my Call tree in profiling]

Comment: What thread are you calling reload on?

Comment: did you profile the app?

Comment: @Wain. I am calling this on Main thread by  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   
                     });

Comment: @engmahsa I am not good at profiling.. :(

Comment: And what's it doing if you pause it?

Comment: @wain. I dont know how to pause it. But once it gets freeze then it wont come back to normal ever.

Comment: it's easy you can do it .  choose profile , instead of Run from top bar of Xcode . then you can do the flow on device when app freezed , pause program execution and check the related list . wanna chat?

Comment: ok let me try profiling.. i will get back to you soon

Comment: CPU Usage is 100% when it freeze

Comment: wait I'm taking screen shot

Comment: I have updated my question.. please see my call tree in Stack trace(Profiling)

Comment: I guess the problem is "indexPath.row%2==0" cell for calls n times and each time it calculate devision

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93902/discussion-between-engmahsa-and-mani-murugan).

Comment: i think this profile was before your calling  reloadData, can you show your profile during the reload data ?

Comment: i think i got it
can you  use : `LessionTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier ForIndexPath:indexpath];` and notify me about the result , please show your implementation of custom cell :)